# Opening up the Why-does-God-break-the-10-commandments? question

Tags: discussion, closed-questions, specific-question, completed

**[Why doesn't God have to keep his own commandments such as “Do not murder”?](https://christianity.stackexchange.com/q/29813/6071)**

This question is currently marked as a duplicate of another question even though they are about very different questions.

I've edited it to make it clear what this question is about, and also to make it less opinion based.

1. Do you think it's sufficiently on-topic now? If not, how can we improve it further?
2. If you have reopening privileges will you visit the question? Even if it eventually gets closed again I really think that it shouldn't be marked as a duplicate (which apparently will require it to be reopened.)

Comment: Thanks for the edit. This is a very legitimate question.

Answer (score 2):

Sorry to swing the other way on this, I just voted to close the original, and if it were not marked as a duplicate, I would vote to close the other too.

They are primarily opinion based.

"Why does God ... ?" is entirely unanswerable unless there is a very specific doctrinal framework to start from.

"Should/can a Christian ... ?" is also unanswerable for the same reason.

Yes, they do look like different questions, but they are both off-topic, so there is really no point to change the one marked as duplicate to closed.

Comment: I think the question on fighting in war had an implied scope which was sufficient to stand up to our current standards. I have edited the question to make that scope explicit, which I think keeps it well within the realm of on-topic here.

Comment: @Flimzy I pulled my close vote. It is a bit of the answer justifying the question.

Comment: I think it's a biblical basis question and is on topic. It's not a why does god act this way question, but is really about the applicability of the law.

Comment: @curiousdannii I threw in a reopen vote. Needs four more to reopen. We'll see what happens.

Comment: I'm so confused. In your answer, you said you flip-flopped to a close vote. Then in your comments, it looks like you flip-flopped again.

Comment: @JimG. Yeah. Flimzy convinced me and also edited the question to make it a bit better.